# Deployment grails app using tomcat 7 - datasets not loading

Tags: mysql, tomcat, grails, web-deployment

I am currently deploying an application using Apache Tomcat 7
Debugged the errors now and by changing localhost -> I.P., we are able to access the pages, but other users are not able to access the datasets. This maybe due to many reasons, MySQL is not allowing them etc

Backend #1 : My own MySQL Server at Local

```
ERROR : dataset is not defined
```

This could be due to the reason that mysql server is not allowing access to other users as privileges are not given yet.

Backend #2 : Then, I tried my company's MySQL server.
This database can be accessed by all, using a particular set of credentials and also the particular "Host".

```
ERROR : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/composite2/Tablev1/datejson. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://172.21.24.24:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

 dataset is not defined
```

In the second case, my "Datasource.groovy"

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
           //dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://10.1.70.13/ewacs?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            username = "w"
            password = "w@123"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            //dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://10.1.70.13/ewacs?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            username = "w"
            password = "w@123"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            //dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://10.1.70.13/ewacs?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            username = "w"
            password = "w@123"
        }
    }
}
```

In both the cases, the datasets are not loading. What am I doing wrong in case #2?
The access should be there for other users to hit the mysql server.

Why am I getting the error? Tried looking it up, but did not find any relevant link yet.
I went through this link :  [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)
But, I'm a beginner here, not able to understand this at all.

UPDATE:

Ok, so I noticed that in my javascript files, I was still using localhost, big mistake!
I changed localhost -> 10.1.70.13

So, new error now...

```
GET http://10.1.70.13:8080/composite2/Tablev1/datejson net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

OR

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

What is the issue here?

All approaches/suggestions are most welcome.